# Comparing two numbers lists with each other in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame (possibly a list):

```
A = ['01', '20', '02', '25', '26']
B = ['10', '13', '14', '64', '32']
```

I would like to compare list 'a' with list 'b' in the following way:

[image]

As you can see, strings of numbers in the left column with strings in the right column are compared. Combined are strings that have the same boundary digit, one of which is removed during merging (or after). Why was the string '010' removed? Because each digit can occur only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform a couple of string slicing operations and then merge on the common digit.

```
a

    A
0  01
1  20
2  02
3  25
4  26

b

    B
0  10
1  13
2  14
3  64
4  32

a['x'] = a.A.str[-1]
b['x'] = b.B.str[0]
b['B'] = b.B.str[1:]

m = a.merge(b)
```

You could also do this in a single line with `assign`, without disrupting the original dataframes:

```
m = a.assign(x=a.A.str[-1]).merge(b.assign(x=b.B.str[0], B=b.B.str[1:]))
```

For uniques, you'll need to convert to `set` and check its length.

```
v = (m['A'] + m['B'])
v.str.len() == v.apply(set).str.len()

0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
dtype: bool

v[v.str.len() == v.apply(set).str.len()].tolist()
['013', '014', '264']
```

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ interesting approach, actually the length study solves the matter :) interesting whether the colleagues above finished a lively discussion :) I will not be bothering them: D

Answer (score 0):

Something you should be aware of is that you're actually passing integers, not strings. That means that `A = [01, 20, 02, 25, 26]` is the same as `A = [1, 20, 2, 25, 26]`. If you always know that you're going to be working with integers <= 99, however, this won't be an issue. Otherwise, you should use strings instead of integers, like `A = ['01', '20', '02', '25', '26']`. So the first thing you should do is convert the lists to lists of strings. If you know all of the integers will be <= 99, you can do so like this:

```
A = ['%02d' % i for i in A]
B = ['%02d' % i for i in B]
```

(you could also name these something different if you want to preserve the integer lists). Then here would be the solution:

```
final = []
for i in A:
    for j in B:
        if i[-1] == j[0]:
            final.append(i + j[1:])
```

Comment: Please look at the tag before answering the question.